# Applying CSS from an Angular component to a sub-component

Tags: css, angular

We have an in-house Angular component library (one project), each component has basic styling.

We use this library in our App (another project).

A component in the App contains a component from our library.

From the global styles.scss in the App, I can target the elements in the library component just fine.

If I move that global CSS into the App component CSS file, try what may, I cannot target any elements inside the library component.

app-component.html

```html
<div class="outter">
  <library-component specificityattr></library-component>
</div>
```

library-component.html

```html
<div class="generic-styles">
  <p class="hello">Hello</p>
</div>
```

app-component.scss

```
library-component[specificityattr] p.hello {
    background: red;
}
```

styles.scss

```
library-component[specificityattr] p.hello {
    background: green;
}
```

Without the selector in styles.scss, I expect the P tag to have a red background.
Only when I put the same selector in styles.scss do I get a green background.

How is this failing?

What is the correct way to style a components sub-components?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `:host` component is th `library-component` and you want to apply css to some "deep" DOMS so it means [`:ng-deep`](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/)

[Here is working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-kx8akv?file=src/app/app.component.css)

**Use**

```
:host library-component[specificityattr] ::ng-deep p.hello {
    background: green;
}
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: Thank you - I took the time to read this page:

https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/

Which made me understand what was happening above:  The :host targets the instance of this component, and the ::ng-deep removes the attempt to target this components direct content (and it's this part that allows you to target the sub-component)

What it worrying is it's vaguely marked as 'depricated' but the idea being implemented seems sound.  Time will tell!

Answer (score 1):

What you are experiencing is an effect of the default `ViewEncapsulation` of components in Angular.

When you define a component such as below, the view encapsulation of the component will be the default value, which I've included inside a comment. This means that Angular won't create a so called 'shadow DOM' for your component, and all the styles will only be applied to your component.

**Encapsulated component**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    //encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated
})
```

If you instead want to apply the styles not only to your component, you can specify a specific `ViewEncapsulation` in your component declaration. Using `ViewEncapsulation.None` will move the styles to the DOM head, and it will still not create a shadow DOM.

**Without encapsulation**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Have a look at [this StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-93ons1)

It's important to keep in mind that `ViewEncapsulation.None` will *"leak"* your styles to other components, which in turn will make it harder to style your application unless you know exactly where your styles are defined.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I think your answer may appear to do the job, but I specifically was looking for _if_ a component should be allowed to style any sub-components, and _how_ it may do so.  I think your answer doesn't address this broader conceptual question - but it's still useful for me to go look at these options to understand the wider scenario better.

Comment: The _if_ it should be able to style a child component is primarily opinion based, and the _how_ I answered. You specifically asked _"How is this failing?"_ which is what I answered. I'm glad you found my answer helpful though, but be more precise in case you want more suitable answers! :)

Comment: you are the life savior bro up voted it solved my problem stuck in this from last 7 days

Comment: Glad the answer was useful, @DeepakGoyal!

Comment: but hot to stop css leak as we move to some other link than its use the previous page css is it possible like from url1 i use skin2 by encapsulation but my default skin is skin1.css but when i move to url 2 it still use skin2 not using skin1.css as its my default skin

Answer (score 0):

check the css file that is produced at the end.

it looks like the first is physically before the second hence it's green

```
library-component[specificityattr] p.hello {
    background: red;
}

library-component[specificityattr] p.hello {
    background: green;
}
```